# detecting search key-press in iOS when input field is NOT a UISearchBar

Tags: ios

In my web browser app, user needs to type in a search input field on a web-site. Note, this is not a UISearchBar, but the website input field.

Now, I want to detect if the user pressed `search` key on the keyboard. Is it possible?

Again, the field is not a UISearchBar and so, the delegate method `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` doesn't help.

thanks,

Nikhil

Comment: This is an existing web site that you want to capture searches into, or is it user interface you've created but opted to display in HTML?

Comment: it is existing web site or websites I may say. I want to have this behavior generically, not some particular site in particular.

Comment: Don't think it is possible. Selecting links, on the otherhand... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217679/uiwebview-capturing-clicks

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard itself doesn't offer any such functionality — you can't just do something as simple as, hypothetically, `[[UIKeyboard sharedKeyboard] setDelegate:self]`. You'll notice that all the keyboard-related notifications like `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` are explicitly posted with a nil object, so it's fairly certain that Apple explicitly doesn't want to expose any sort of direct relationship to the keyboard, no doubt so that things like physical keyboards work correctly.

So I think your best bet is to catch `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` and inspect the request to find out whether it's a form post. I'm no web standard expert but I believe that if it is then then `HTTPMethod` will be `POST` and the content type will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.